# Sum of divisors(n!)/n! is greater than Harmonic Number(n)

Tags: number-theory, summation, harmonic-numbers

Prove that if n is a natural number, then  $\frac{\sigma(n!)}{n!}$ $\ge$ $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{i}}$

I thought I would have to do something like showing $\frac{\sigma(n!)}{n!}$ $\ge$ $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\frac{n!}{n! * i}}$ and then canceling for each term on the right side and left side to show the left side was greater, but I can't get any further.

Comment: Every summand on the right is a summand on the left, and then some.

Comment: Consider the set $\{n!, \frac{n!}{2}, \frac{n!}{3}, \ldots \frac{n!}{n}\}$. Note that each of these integers divides $n!$.